# Using published pipeline artifact in azure devops using YAML

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a simple helloworld c++ program, and I am writing a pipeline to get familiar with the azure environment.
However, I have created multiple stages, with individual jobs inside the stages.
I have a build stage where I compile my source code to produce an object file.

I can execute the file in the same job without any issues, however I want to create a separate stage for execution. Since I need to share the files now between stages, I use pipeline artifact. However, I am not able to download the artifact. It produces an error - **"Unexpected value ''"** at line 37.

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest


stages:
  - stage: Analysis
    jobs:
      - job: AnalyisJob
        steps:
          - script: echo Analysing the cpp file
  
  - stage: Build
    jobs:
      - job: BuildJob
        steps:
          - script: |
              echo compiling the cpp file
              g++ helloworld.cpp -o helloworld
              echo finished compiling
              echo "publishing the object file"
          - publish: 
            target: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
            artifact: 'MyArtifact'

  - stage: Test
    jobs:
      - job: Test
        steps:
          - download:                  #ERROR LINE 37
            artifact: 'MyArtifact'
          - script: |
              echo running the cpp file
              ./helloworld
```

Any suggestions to overcome this?

---

**UPDATE**

I used the suggestion and got the error rectified, but now I face permission denied error to run by object file.

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest


stages:
  - stage: Analysis
    jobs:
      - job: AnalyisJob
        steps:
          - script: echo Analysing the cpp file
  
  - stage: Build
    jobs:
      - job: BuildJob
        steps:
          - script: |
              echo compiling the cpp file
              g++ helloworld.cpp -o helloworld
              echo finished compiling
              echo "publishing the contents"
          - publish: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
            artifact: MyArtifact

  - stage: Test
    jobs:
      - job: Test
        steps:
         - download: current
           artifact: MyArtifact
         - script: |
              echo running the cpp file
              cd  $(Pipeline.Workspace)/MyArtifact
              ./helloworld
```

The error image :
[image: Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `current`:

```
- download: current
```

See the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#download-artifacts).

Comment: Could you please look into the update?

Comment: need maybe to give him permissions with `chmod`

Comment: if i do a ```cat helloworld.cpp``` it works! I can see the contents of the file

Comment: But doing a ```./helloworld``` gives an error

Comment: what is ./helloworld? c++ file? what do you want to do with him?

Comment: it is just a file which prints helloworld. I want to have a scenario where I compile the cpp file in one stage and use pipeline artifacts to execute the executable in another stage

Comment: but what is the content of this file? cpp? or bash?

Comment: its cpp file.. ```#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    return 0;
}```

Comment: you can't cpp code just with `./helloworld` I guess.. but maybe create a new question about it..